# How to Notify Property Changes Inside Recycler View?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

Can anyone give me a sample of above page in recycler view with this design and also notify quantity changes on the plus/minus button

I want to implement this type of page in Xamarin Android

Please provide me a sample

Comment: This question is too broad - you do not have your own code, and you expect us to give an entire example that looks exactly like this.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: yes it solved..

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Add a listener  on the **EditText** .

```
myHolder.editText1.AddTextChangedListener(new MyWatcher());
```

And implement `ITextWatcher` in class **MyWatcher**

```
using Android.Text;

public class InputTextWatcher : : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
        // do something you want
    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        // do something you want
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        // do something you want
    }
}
```

#### 2.Or you can use the event handlers instead:

```
myHolder.editText1.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
{

};
```